# dy.drop_fields() vs DropFields.apply()

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

When using Glue I came across two ways to remove columns from a dynamic frame.

A method of the DynamicFrame: [drop_fields()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame.html#aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame-drop_fields)
and the class [DropFields.apply()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-transforms-DropFields.html#aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-transforms-DropFields-name)

they are used like this:

```py
dy_reduced_data = dy_raw_data.drop_fields(cols_to_drop)

dy_reduced_data = DropFields.apply(frame = dy_raw_data, paths = [cols_to_drop])
```

Now I wonder: Is there any difference between them? Is one more efficient? They seem to have the same scope of options.
Is there a best practice which of the two to use? or when to use which?

Glue usually suggests the transformation classes, but they seem much more lengthy and less readable to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only answer parts of that question:

> Is there any difference between them?

No, the Class-Style transforms actually call the underlying `DynamicFrame` methods:

From the library:

```py
class DropFields(GlueTransform):
    """
    Drop fields within a DynamicFrame

    # ... (ommited stuff for brevity, the __call__ matters)
    """

    def __call__(self, frame, paths, transformation_ctx = "", info = "", stageThreshold = 0, totalThreshold = 0):
        return frame.drop_fields(paths, transformation_ctx, info, stageThreshold, totalThreshold)
```

> Is one more efficient?

The DynamicFrame method may be slightly more efficient because of the tiny bit of performance overhead for a function call, but not noticeable.

> Is there a best practice when to use which?

No idea.